# Saying Yaale v'Yavo out loud to remind others during Amida

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, loud-quiet

Some people recite Yaale v'Yavo out loud while saying the Amida prayer, to remind others to say it. This would help others who would have forgotten from having to repeat the entire Shmonei Esrei. Is this practice against halacha, considering that it is supposed to be a silent prayer?

Comment: "considering that it is supposed to be a silent prayer." Source?

Comment: @Mithrandir We normally do not change people's choice of transcribing style.

Comment: @Adám I was only making it consistent, as they had capitalized Yaale V'Yavo in the question. (Also: You un-capitalized *amida*, which the OP had capitalized.)

Comment: @Mithrandir You're right, I missed that. Rolled back to your version. Sorry.

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct. If there is additional information that you want, consider clarifying what it is.

Answer (score 11):

Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach is quoted in Halichos Shlomo (page 98 note 20) saying that the minhag for the mispallelim to raise ones voice when saying "V'sein Tal Umatar Lebracha" and other similar additions (including Yaaleh Veyavo) in the middle of the Amidah with the intention of reminding others is incorrect, as it is disrepectful to G-d, for it is improper to act that way when standing in front of a Melech - King. However, if it is the Gabbai [as mentioned in the Magen Avraham [114:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x481)], it is permitted.

[The Debreciner Rav](http://kevarim.com/rabbi-moshe-stern/)  Rav Moshe Stern ([שו״ת באר משה חלק ד׳ סימן י׳](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14710&st=&pgnum=313)) permits it, but only for one person, for if many people call out, it may lead to confusion and may be treated lightly by the mispallelim.

> אולם אינו נכון ***שהרבה בנ״א יעשו כן*** זאח״ז כי זה  מבלבל המתפללים  ואסור
>   לעשות כדבר הזה, ע״כ אחר  שאחד כבר הגביה קולו להזכיר הצבור שלא ישכחו 
>   מלומר ״יעלה ויבא״ או ״על הנסים״ ***אסור לאחרים***  לעשות כן כי מבלבל את
>   הרבים וגם לפעמים הוא  צחוק בעיני המתפללים ומביאם לידי עבירה חמורה 
>   באמצע תפלה בלחש.‏

Comment: This is a little strange, the Magen Avraham talk about the Shanash which remember befor the prayer.

Comment: Im just qouting the footnote.

Comment: the topic of siman 114 is about starting to say, not a problem of remembering. The Shats itself, if he said it out loud, is not counted as azkara, only when saying chazarat hashats/

Comment: good..... in name of maharshal,

Answer (score 5):

The answer of @Shoel U'Meshiv is true and good. I just want to show the inner side of this Halacha.

#### [SA OC 236, 2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1062)

> אין לספר בין גאולה דערבית לתפלה ואף הנוהגין לומר שמונה עשרה פסוקים ויראו עינינו אין להפסיק בין יראו עינינו לתפלה ***ומיהו מה שמכריז שליח ציבור ראש חדש בין קדיש לתפלת ערבית לא הוי הפסק כיון שהוא צורך התפלה*** וכן יכול לומר ברכו להוציא מי שלא שמע ולא הוי הפסק. ‏
>
> It is prohibited to speak betweeen the blessing "Geula" of Arvit and the prayer (Amida). It is prohibited despite the allowance to read 18 verses "Veyir'u Einenu...". Therefore, the custom in which the Shaliach Tsibur annunce "Yaale Veyavo" between the Kaddish and the Prayer is not considered as an interruption because it is for the need of the prayer.

Magen Avraham in sk 1 (א) said.

> ועוד דתפילת ערבית רשות, (שו"ת הרשב"א רצ"ג)‏ ועין סימן קס"ז וכן נוהגין דלא כרש"ל (ב"ח)‏ ומכל מקום אפשר דוקא בראש חודש שהוא דאורייתא או בתן טל ומטר דמחזירים אותו אם לא אמרו. מה שאין כן בחנוכה ופורים שאין מחזרירין אותו אם לא אמרו אפשר שאין מכריזין ומכל מקום ומכל מקום המנהג להכריז וכן כתב הרב דוד אבודרהם ונראה לי דבין הפרקים דינן כמו בשחרית ודווקא בין גאולה לתפילה יש מקילין משום דתפילת ערבית רשות אבל בין קריאת שמע וברכותיה חובה לכולי עלמא. ‏
>
> This passage of Magen Avraham talk about announce of Yaale Veyavo or Al Hanissim. He shows **two views**,

1. the view of Shulchan Aruch following Shut Harashba, which allows
   from *two reasons*.

   - The first is a need for the community (as the
     allowance to speak between Hamotsi and eating bread "keep salt, give
     its meal to Bull").
   - The second is specific to Arvit, in which the
     Prayer (Amida is facculative and not an obligation as Mincha and
     Shacharit). Magen Avraham said that this view is ruled, not only by
     Shulchan Aruch but also by Abudarham. Anyway for Yaale Veyavo and
     Veten Tal Umatar, he ruled this view. But for Al Hanissim which is
     less important (if someone forgot to say it, he do not need to pray
     again), he pasken not to announce, {but [Mishna Berura sk 7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=296) allowed even for Al Hanissim.}

2.The view of Maharshal, in its notes (on Siman 237, not found), which is reported by the **Bach** [**236, sk 3**](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x945). Bellow I'll quote a statement from the Maharshal in Hebrew and English explanation:

#### Here will be mentionned a case in which someone have to annunce "Yaale Veyavo!" in middle of its own Amida.

> ולכן יראה שהשמש יקדים תפלתו שיוכל להגיע ליעלה ויבוא קודם
>   הקהל ויכריז בתפלתו עכ״ל
>
> A less problematic solution to annunce is that the Shamash will begin his Prayer before Tsibur and *saying out loud Yaale Veyavo, make a clear annunce* for people. {For the Rashba, A fortiori, it is allowed, because lake of basic prohibition}. **Maharshal's allowance is wholly accepted but his stringency is not.**

For the intervention of other people see the answer of @Shoel U'Meshiv.

@Shoel U'Meshiv it is only a supplement for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

OU Israel publishes [Torah Tidbits](https://www.ouisrael.org/programs/torah-tidbits-weekly-english-torah-publication/), "the largest weekly English-language Torah publication in Israel."

This [tti tidbits edition](http://www.ttidbits.com/952/952.txt) says

> Something that really shouldn't be done - anytime - is to say things
>   out loud in the middle of one's silent Amida. Many people think they
>   are being helpful by saying Morid HaTal or Yaaleh V'Yavo or Al HaNisim
>   or whatever aloud, but it should not be done.

Comment: What is the source of this interesting psak?

Comment: dont see any source there. not so useful without that